# Wpf App "Cannot resolve symbol 'DatePicker'" Rider 2021.2.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rider

I was trying to do some simple wpf app, but i couldn't use DatePicker class in my .xaml file.
Is it some kind of Rider problem? In VS there wasnt problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue in Rider. Actually it should work:

[image]

I suggest to create a minimal repro project and fire an issue in JetBrains public issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER